# Counting the number of unique values by date in R

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, unique

Please help me to count the number of unique IDs per Date.
so, initially, there is this data frame of IDs and dates

```
 ID         Date 
 1        2009/11/1
 1        2009/11/2
 1        2009/11/2
 2        2009/11/1
 2        2009/11/1
 2        2009/11/2 
 3        2009/11/1
 3        2009/11/3
```

It is possible to rearrange it by date. If we do so then we will see that on the 1st there are 3 unique IDs. On the 2ed 2 unique ID and on the 3rd there is one unique ID. So the final table should look like this:

```
  Date      uniqueIDs
2009/11/1      3
2009/11/2      2
2009/11/3      1
```

I know that it is possible to aggregate with `aggregate`  by using `sum` if the value is '1' or '0 'like that:

```
aggregate(DataFrame$RoomAv ~ DataFrame$Date, DataFrame, sum)
```

But how to **count** the unique number of IDs per day? The ID column is an integer column.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What product is this? Is it a database a spreadsheet or something else? Can you add some details so we can help you.

Comment: Its a data frame.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way you can do:

```
# using data.table

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,uniqueN(ID),.(Date)]

        Date V1
1: 2009/11/1  3
2: 2009/11/2  2
3: 2009/11/3  1


# using dplyr

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(uniqueid = n_distinct(ID))

  Date      uniqueid
  <chr>        <int>
1 2009/11/1        3
2 2009/11/2        2
3 2009/11/3        1
```

Comment: tried it as df <- setDT(calendar)[,uniqueN(calendar$ID),.(calendar$DATE)] but it shoews each data with zero unique values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)

rawData <-"ID,Date 
 1,2009/11/1
 1,2009/11/2
 1,2009/11/2
 2,2009/11/1
 2,2009/11/1
 2,2009/11/2 
 3,2009/11/1
 3,2009/11/3 "

data <- read.csv(text = rawData,as.is=TRUE)

sqlStmt <- "select Date, count(distinct ID) from data group by Date"
sqldf(sqlStmt)
```

...and the output:

```
> sqldf(sqlStmt)
       Date count(distinct ID)
1 2009/11/1                  3
2 2009/11/2                  2
3 2009/11/3                  1
>
```